# VS2013 RTM making once per second Signal R requests when I check with fiddler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, fiddler

When I check with Fiddler I see my new install of VS2013 is giving Continuous Signal R requests. I don't use anything to do with this in my application. How can I stop these requests which I assume are part of VS2013 trying to sync up something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's probably due to the BrowserLink feature mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx).  BrowserLink uses SignalR to communicate between VS and your browsers.

Comment: +1 Great link! Also happy to see that it is easy to disable that "feature". Love Visual Studio but not that "thing". Thanks again!

Comment: You can use FiddlerScript to filter out those unwanted requests whilst keeping BrowserLink enabled.  See the following gist: https://gist.github.com/janv8000/8972599

Answer (score 0):

Maybe log out of VisualStudio? It might also help if you tell us where VS is communicating to...

Comment: Nope it's a problem with all the VS2013 we installed here. I do recall fixing it before with one of the options but I can't find which one. It's going to be annoying for the next 50,000 people as the start installing VS2013.

Comment: Can you tell us where VS is communicating? Fiddler should have that information.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two additional calls made by the browser-link:

- a one off call made on a page render, on the same port as the site exchanging information about the mapping between Razor views and the elements.  This call has `__browserlink` at the start of the URL.
- a periodic call as part of the SignalR synchronisation.  This has `SignalR` about 30 characters into the URL.

The former, a single call, I can live with.  The other fills up my capture history.

To avoid this, in fiddler I've used the **'Hide the following Hosts'** option in the **Filter Tab** and put something like `localhost:62533` in the text box.  Note that port number seems to change with each restart of VS2013.

As long as the 'Use Filters' is checked, I still see the traffic I want to (plus a one-off call for `__browserlink`).